# Can't reference sibling projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class which I want to use the Ninja class present in it. These live in the Namespace `NinjaDomain.Classes`.

But for some reason in another project, Console Application, I can't actually reference it! It's not letting me reference the one in `NinjaDomain.Classes`

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any warning message?

Comment: Have you added a reference from your console application to your `NinjaDomain.Classes` project in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Nope, never did that. I thought these were only for external references. Updated and fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't added the reference of your sibling project. Go to **Solution Explorer**, right click on **References** of your project, select **Add Reference** and then on left hand side choose **Shared Projects**. You will see your sibling project there. Select it and add to your project.